# I don't understand an equation of motion (for biological cells)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, biophysics

In a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.74.061908) about cell dynamics ([pdf](http://balintszabo.web.elte.hu/collectivecells/PRE_74_061908.pdf))
I cannot understand equation (3), because there is an 'arcsin' of a vector.

Let $\theta_i(t)$ be the orientational angle for cell number $i$ at time $t$, $\vec{n}_i(t)$ it's preferred direction of propulsion at time $t$, $\vec{v}_i(t)$ it's velocity at time $t$, $\tau$ a relaxation time constant and $\xi$ a stochastic force (it is a Gaussian random noise) acting on the cell. Moreover $\vec{e}_z$ is the unit vector in z-direction. Then in this paper the equation of motion is written as follows:

$$\frac{d \theta_i}{dt} = \frac{1}{\tau}\mathrm{arcsin}\left(\left(\vec{n}_i(t)\frac{\vec{v}_i(t)}{|\vec{v}_i(t)|}\right) \cdot \vec{e}_z\right)+\xi$$

The quantity

$$\vec{n}(t)\frac{\vec{v}(t)}{|\vec{v}(t)|}$$

is a scalar; why it is multiplied by another vector (here $\vec{e}_z$) and then the $\arcsin$-Operator is applied?

They say that this is a relaxation term for the orientation of a cell. Does somebody understand what is meant with this term? Maybe a vector in the argument of the arcsin is overfluent (i.e. there is a typo error)?

Comment: Can you make this question self-contained? If the link dies the question loses its value. If you can add a small sketch and the equation you are referring to, this would make it a lot clearer, and easier to answer.

Comment: Ok I will change the question; thank you!

Comment: $\vec{n}\frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}$ is definitely not a scalar  as there isn't a dot product sign between them (that might be the typo), the best people to ask at this point would be the authors of the paper themselves.

Comment: If it would be a rank 2 tensor, then, after dot product with $\vec{e}_z$, it results in a vector again. Maybe it could be $arcsin(\vec{n}(t)\frac{\vec{v}_i(t)}{|\vec{v}_i(t)|})$ and the z-unitvector is just the direction of the angle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that there is a cross product symbol missing:

$$\frac{d \theta_i}{dt} = \frac{1}{\tau}\mathrm{arcsin}\left[\left(\vec{n}_i(t) \times \frac{\vec{v}_i(t)}{|\vec{v}_i(t)|}\right) \cdot \vec{e}_z\right]+\xi$$

That way, the rate of correction would grow with the angle between actual and desired velocity.